# Majority encryption algorithm?

Tags: symmetric, secret-sharing, complexity, multiple-encryption

Assume that I want to leave an encrypted message to a group of $n$ people in a way that they can only decrypt it if they work together in the following sense:

For some fixed $k < n$ every sub-group of $k$ or more people should be able to decrypt the message while less people do not suffice.

One way to do this would be generating keys $r_1^S,\ldots,r_k^S$ for every subset $S$ of $k$ people in a way that $r_1^S,\ldots,r_{k-1}^S$ are random and $r_1^S\oplus \ldots \oplus r_k^S=q$ where $q$ is the secret key to any symmetric encryption algorithm.

If $k$ people choose to cooperate they can simply add up their keys (corresponding to that set of $k$ people) and decrypt my message.

The problem is that this procedure is very inefficient: For $n=100,k=30$ we would already need to generate $\binom{100}{30}\approx 3\cdot 10^{25}$ sets of keys. Is there any more efficient different way to solve this problem?

Comment: Are you looking for a secret sharing scheme? see [Shamir's secret sharing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shamir%27s_Secret_Sharing). Or do you want help for the scheme you described?

Comment: Look for Secret sharing and Threshold Encryption

Comment: @Blub your comment actually answers my question. Feel free to post it as a full answer so I can accept it.